# C# & ASP.NET MVC access URL without login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which has its own login. Whenever I access any URL for the first time, it automatically sends me to the login page, if the user session does not exists.

I need to access a certain URL, from the application without any login redirect or session check.

e.g. https://www.testsite.com/Controller/View/id

When I access this URL from another application, I don't want the user to be redirected to a login page.

How can I do this? I tried using `CustomAuthorize` controller, but as per my logs, it goes through `CustomAuthorize`, then view page and then redirects to the login page.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

I use `[CustomAuthorize]` attribute on the controller function -

```
public ActionResult ViewTest(id)
{ }
```

It passes through the `CustomAuthorize.cs` controller and then -

```
return view();
```

in ViewTest, only to be sent to the login page finally.

I want the page to be shown instead of redirecting to login.

I am also setting any session required in the `CustomAuthorize.cs` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute that can be used on either controller or action

```
[Authorize]
public class FooBarController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Foo()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

In the above example `Bar()` cannot be accessed without a user session, but `Foo()` can.

Comment: [SessionTimeout]
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]
public class FooBarController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
    }
}

**********---------------*************

This is how my code looks, and it is still redirecting to Login Page


**********---------------*************